# Spring-boot working different on two computers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I try to learn spring boot and thus I am writing a simple application. For the moment there is not much code in it, only pom.xml and Main class. Here is contents of pom:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>checkingboot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>checkingboot</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PortalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PortalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I run the code on one computer it works fine. On another however, while trying to run it (either from IntelliJ or with mvn clean install) I get

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException...

My question is - why is this happening and how to fix it? (I have the current version of jdk installed on both machines as well as the current version of maven)

Comment: may be due to corrupted jars. Try to clean and update your project

Comment: @KathirvelSubramanian I tried that, to no result though

Answer (score 0):

Ok - apparently I was mistaken about environments - at one machine (working) i have java 8 installed while on the one not working I have java 10, and thus i get problem answered here:

[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)